# How to do pagination in postgres using table primary id

Tags: postgresql

I have posts table, primary key is id integer, and a ranking field that is integer as well. I want to be able to do pagination using the post id.

i.e. if I have the following posts ids [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12]

I want to say in my api /api/posts?postId=3&page=2&size=3 (assuming page start from 1)

and I get in return 6, 8, and 10 as response.

The goal that I have a website, that list posts, users share a post, the link basically open the same page list but the first post is the post that was clicked, and next/follow up posts will be next posts in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the statement to retrieve specific ordered set from a table.

```
SELECT *
FROM Posts_Table
LIMIT [firstPostToBeShown], [firstPostToBeShown + pagesize]
```

If you want your api to return 10 pages with one query .

```
originalpostid integer := [originalpostid];
pagesize INT := [pagesize];
page INT := [numOfPage];
loopindex INT := 1;
localfirstpost := originalpostid;

WHILE loopindex <= page
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Posts_Table
    LIMIT  originalpostid , originalpostid+(loopindex*pagesize)

SET loopindex = loopindex + 1;
SET originalpostid = originalpostid + (loopindex*pagesize) + 1 ;
END;
```